# How to use bootstrap 3 checkbox property in asp.net checkbox component properly?

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 in asp.net and using the checkbox class but it shows me extra padding or margin [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipFru.png).

How can I fix it.

This is sample code.

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" Text="I accept terms and conditions" runat="server" /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are using asp.net server side checkbox it has its own styling.In order to make your code as it and just you want to make layout of checkbox to be perfect then you need to write extra css which will overwrite the Bootstrap css.Below is the code which will fix your issue just using css:-

**Bootstrap code for checkbox:-**
    .checkbox input[type=checkbox] {margin-left: -20px;}

**Customize code** in order to make checkbox to appear near to text or label
    .checkbox input[type=checkbox] {margin-left: 0px;   // play with margin left to adjust the checkbox input.}

**Second approach** is that just copy paste the code from bootstrap for checkbox as it is and add runat ="server" in  the code like this:-

```html
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox1" runat="server"> I accept terms and conditions
    </label>
  </div>
```

the above code will treat html as asp.net server code.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<div class="form-check col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="I accept terms and conditions" Checked="false" />
</div>
```